# Clozure CL Foreign variable "O_NONBLOCK" not found

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a question about Clozure CL.
While I was trying to quickload a package from quicklisp.
It throws out an error. Have googled it, but nothing useful found.

Here is the error message:

```
(ql:quickload :drakma)
To load "drakma":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    drakma
; Loading "drakma"
..
Read error between positions 6342 and 6532 in     /Users/Mac/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cl+ssl-20111105-git/streams.lisp.
> Error: Foreign variable "O_NONBLOCK" not found
> While executing: CCL::%LOAD-VAR, in process Listener(6).
```

Thank you in advance

I've asked on mailing list:

## answer from mailing list:

If you move or rename the "darwin-x86-headers" directory (or otherwise
try to simulate an incomplete installation):

`[src/ccl-dev] gb@antinomial> mv darwin-x86-headers64 darwin-x86-headers64X`

and then run CCL and try to access something (O_NONBLOCK) defined in the
interface files in that directory:

`[src/ccl-dev] gb@antinomial> ccl64

Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.8-dev-r15225M-trunk  (DarwinX8664)!

? #$O_NONBLOCK`

you get a warning or two about the missing interface files

```
; Warning: Interface file #P"/usr/local/src/ccl-dev/darwin-x86-headers64/libc/constants.cdb" does         not exist, and the containing directory does not exist.
;          This may mean that that the "ccl:" logical-pathname host has not been properly initialized. ; While executing: CDB-OPEN, in process listener(1).
; Warning: Interface file #P"/usr/local/src/ccl-dev/darwin-x86-headers64/libc/vars.cdb" does not exist, and the containing directory does not exist.
;          This may mean that that the "ccl:" logical-pathname host has not been properly initialized.
```

before getting the same error that you reported.

If you use Quicklisp to load some code that tries to lookup that constant's value
in (missing) database files, you don't see that warning.

On the other hand, you do see dot characters printed when using
Quicklisp.  (Sometimes lots of them !)

I don't claim to be part of Quicklisp's target audience, but I had a vote
I think I'd vote for being able to see progress messages and diagnostics
(even if that meant seeing fewer dots and even - especially - if the diagnostics
indicate an installation problem, as they seem to in this case.)

To stop flaming and try to address the original question, if the interface directory
is moved back to where CCL expects it to be, then:

```
? #$O_NONBLOCK
4
```

things work as expected.  (If they didn't, it wouldn't be possible to compile
CCL itself or to compile lots of other code that uses the FFI's reader macros.)
That means that my best guess is that CCL isn't installed correctly on your
system.  I don't know that with absolute certainty and I don't have any way
of knowing how it's installed on your system, but I believe that if it's installed
the way that the manual and website suggest problems like this are avoided.

Comment: probably best to use the support mailing list of the respective maintainers...

Comment: I use Clozure CL. This answer is from CCL mailing list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CCL installation is incomplete or incorrect. Try asking on the CCL mailing list about it.